# Loop Select and Update PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not finding the error. I need to update a table based on the lowest date for each item by removing duplicates.

```
FOR temprow IN
   SELECT MIN(orcitem_dtime_inclusao), orcitem_orc_id FROM orcamento_itens GROUP BY orcitem_orc_id ORDER BY orcitem_orc_id ASC
LOOP
  UPDATE orcamentos SET orc_dtime_orcamento = temprow.orcitem_dtime_inclusao WHERE orc_id = temprow.orcitem_orc_id;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: *"I'm not finding the error."* what error? Does it throw an error? Does it not update the table? Or ain't the update correct? OR something else? What's the problem?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
UPDATE orcamentos o
    SET orc_dtime_orcamento = oi.min_orcitem_dtime_inclusao
    FROM (SELECT orcitem_orc_id,
                 MIN(orcitem_dtime_inclusao) as min_orcitem_dtime_inclusao
          FROM orcamento_itens
          GROUP BY orcitem_orc_id
         ) oi
    WHERE oi.orcitem_orc_id = o.orc_id;
```

You don't need a cursor or other looping mechanism.  You can do this all in a single query.

Comment: Woww. Perfect. Thanks